# Discovery tests failing on very simple scenarios

Tags: apex, unit-test, query

Let me preface this by saying that I am very unfamiliar with Salesforce.  I have written a set of small discovery type tests to try and feel my way through the syntax and how things work, but I am getting stuck with no values coming back from my queries.

```
@isTest
private class SmartSearchTests {
    //works exactly as expected
    static testMethod void trueIsTrue() {
        System.assertEquals(true, true);
    }

    //works as expected
    static testMethod void trueIsNotTrue() {
        System.assertNotEquals(true, false);
    }

    //Same value 0
    static testMethod void canGetASmallListOfContacts() {
        List<Contact> ccs = [SELECT Id from Contact Limit 10];
        System.assertNotEquals(0, ccs.size());
    }

    //invalid ID field: 0Q0M987654AcTg
    static testMethod void canLoadAQuoteById() {
        Quote q = [SELECT Id from Quote where Id = '0Q0M987654AcTg'];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, q);    
    }
}
```

I can see that on the 4th test, I am doing something incorrect by trying to use a string as an Id, but I cannot for the life of me firgure out my the third test returns no data.  The same is true when I run this test against any built in object type and I know there is data there.

Also, does `[SELECT Id from Contact Limit 10]` evaluate to a concrete type?  For example could I pass that block of code around to other functions, i.e., `doSomething(id, [select Id from Account])`?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Take a look at the [tag:unit-test] tag's wiki page: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/unit-test/info for a quick explanation and some good links.

Comment: '0Q0M987654AcTg' is an invalid id; all ids are either 15 or 18 characters but this one is 14. I suspect you mean '00Q' at the start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the detailed explanation here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm

The short answer is that unless you specify it, from an apex test you don't have visibility on the org's existing data, therefore, you need to create it first.

Comment: Thanks!  @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I would not use SeeAllData as an alternative to get around this.  It will solve the problem, but its a very bad habit to get into.  Creating tests that are dependent on your org data is not a good idea.  It is not best practice, I would create your own test data.  Take a look here http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

Comment: @sfdc_ninja - thanks for the pointers.  I will make sure to not use this in a real world case, but am just trying to wrap my head around syntax and usage with discovery type tests.

Comment: No prob.  Just trying to help you in the long run.  Good luck.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja do you think it's okay to use SeeAllData if my main class leverages custom settings to avoid hard coded data? I've created ~40 custom setting records that I'd prefer to not have to re-create in my test class.

Comment: That could be an edge case where it's ok.  Some poeple might set up a test util class that creates all 40 of the custom settings and you can call it from your test class.  You still have ti manually write the code, but you only have to write it once and you can create it all with one line of code from the test class.  Its reusable as well.  I think this is worthy of a new question though to get more visibility and other opinions.  Please add it as a new question, and others can chime in.